# Fielder in contact with fielder near boundary

Tags: rules, cricket

What happens when fielder one is in contact with the ball near boundary and fielder two is in contact with fielder one who is outside of the boundary.

Will it be declared a boundary or not?

Answer (score 3):

As per [Law 19 (BOUNDARIES)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/)

Section 3 (a) (ii)

> a fielder with some part of his person in contact with the ball, touches the boundary or has some part of his person grounded beyond the boundary.

And section 3 (b) *

> The phrases ‘touches the boundary’ and ‘touching the boundary’ shall mean **contact with** either (i) the boundary edge as defined in 2 above or (ii) ***any* person** or obstacle within the field of play which has been designated a boundary by the umpires before the toss.

<sub>*read the bolded part specially</sub>

So as per section 3 (b) if a fielder with some part of his person in contact with the ball touches any person/object outside the boundary line, it will be declared a boundary.

Comment: yup, it will be a boundary

Comment: I am not sure I agree 100% with your interpretaion.
Section 3b - any person or obstacle within the field of play which has been designated a boundary by the umpires before the toss
BEFORE THE TOSS.
Thats before the game starts. Obviously no player can be deamed a boundary before the game starts otherwise he can not take part in the game.
.
I agree with your answer, that he will be out, I am just not sure your interpretation of this law is correct. But I am not knowledged in cricket law enough to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose That section should be parsed as "any person or (obstacle within the field of play which has been designated a boundary)", not "any (person or obstacle) within the field of play which has been designated a boundary".